# JPQL: How to achieve the same functionality as collection member declaration with a where clause?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, jpa, jpql

My entity class is something like this:

```
@Entity
public class Book {
    ...
    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> authors;
    ...
}
```

Now I want query books by inputting an author's name, e.g. **Tom**, but ignore the name's case so **tom/tOm/...** should also match. I know that I can achieve using a collection member declaration:

```
select b from Book b, in(b.authors) a where lower(a) = 'tom'
```

However, in our application framework all JPQL statements are generated from a fixed template:

```
select b from Book b where WHERE_CLAUSE
```

I'm only allowed to provide the where clause. Anybody know how to get the same results as above with this template?

Comment: Change (or ditch) the framework. It's extremely limiting. Not being able to use joins makes it inadequate for 95% of the queries you'll need to execute.

Comment: I also want to do that but there are already too many statements generated from the framework, so changing it is quite risky.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a cheating way:

```
select b from Book b where (b.id in (select bb from Book bb, in(bb.authors) a where lower(a) = 'tom'))
```